# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject works in debug build but crashes in release build

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-4.8

My Winforms app stores settings in a JSON file which the following class manages. It runs fine when the application is built in debug mode but crashes in release mode with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." The code that crashes is JsonConvert.DeserializeObject in the GetSettings method.

- Visual Studio 2022
- .Net 4.8
- Newtonsoft 13.0.2

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MyApp
{
    public sealed class Settings
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public Guid ApplicationId { get; private set; }

        [JsonProperty]
        public string AccessToken { get; private set; }

        private static string fileName = String.Empty;
        private static string FileName
        {
            get
            {
                if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty( fileName ) )
                {
                    fileName = Path.Combine( Folder, "settings.json" );
                }
                return fileName;
            }
        }

        private static string folder = String.Empty;
        private static string Folder
        {
            get
            {
                if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty( folder ) )
                {
                    folder = Path.Combine( Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData ), "Company Name", "Program Name" );
                    try
                    {
                        var directory = Directory.CreateDirectory( folder );
                    }
                    catch ( Exception x )
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine( $"Unable to create settings folder: {folder}" );
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return folder;
            }
        }

        private static Settings instance = null;

        private Settings()
        {
        }

        public static Settings GetSettings()
        {
            if ( instance == null )
            {
                string settingsText = File.ReadAllText( FileName, Encoding.UTF8 );
                instance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>( settingsText );
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

The partial stack trace shows that internally the crash occurs in Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject when calling the Settings ctor:

```
   at MyApp.Settings()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at MyApp.Settings.GetSettings()
...
```

ILSpy decompiles the Newtonsoft API to the following but I haven't found it useful for finding the crash. How can I determine where and why the crash is occurring, and why only in release mode?

```cs
// Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader
public object CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, [Nullable(2)] JsonProperty containerMember, [Nullable(2)] JsonProperty containerProperty, [Nullable(2)] string id, out bool createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
{
    object obj = null;
    if (objectContract.OverrideCreator != null)
    {
        if (objectContract.CreatorParameters.Count > 0)
        {
            createdFromNonDefaultCreator = true;
            return this.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters(reader, objectContract, containerMember, objectContract.OverrideCreator, id);
        }
        obj = objectContract.OverrideCreator(CollectionUtils.ArrayEmpty<object>());
    }
    else if (objectContract.DefaultCreator != null && (!objectContract.DefaultCreatorNonPublic || this.Serializer._constructorHandling == ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor || objectContract.ParameterizedCreator == null))
    {
        obj = objectContract.DefaultCreator();
    }
    else if (objectContract.ParameterizedCreator != null)
    {
        createdFromNonDefaultCreator = true;
        return this.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters(reader, objectContract, containerMember, objectContract.ParameterizedCreator, id);
    }
    if (obj != null)
    {
        createdFromNonDefaultCreator = false;
        return obj;
    }
    if (!objectContract.IsInstantiable)
    {
        throw JsonSerializationException.Create(reader, "Could not create an instance of type {0}. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, objectContract.UnderlyingType));
    }
    throw JsonSerializationException.Create(reader, "Unable to find a constructor to use for type {0}. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, objectContract.UnderlyingType));
}
```

Comment: does your release build have, for example, IL pruning enabled? meaning: is it possible that the `private Settings()` constructor is being removed in the release build? that might explain why `CreateNewObject` is failing

Comment: Another folder, another json.

Comment: is your Settings constructor really empty? it this your real code or justt part ? ... stacktrace points to Settings contructor

Comment: @MarcGravell IL pruning would not have been intentionally enabled. I had also tried making the constructor protected, then public, though the problem persisted.

Comment: @Selvin Yes the Settings constructor really was empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why Json.NET is throwing trying to construct your `Settings` object in release mode.  Possibilities might include:

- Your framework has IL pruning enabled, as suggested by [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell).
- In your release build you are running under partial trust and do not have permission to access private constructors via reflection.

Whatever the problem is, you can work around it easily by allocating the `Settings` object yourself and populating it using [`JsonSerializer.Populate()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Populate_1.htm).

In addition, you have a second problem that could be symptomatic only in release builds: you are not initializing your static singletons `Settings.instance`, `Settings.FileName` and `Settings.Folder` in a thread-safe manner.  For an explanation of why, see [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton) by Jon Skeet.  That article recommends using [`System.Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1) to implement lazy, thread-safe initialization.

Putting all that together, your `Settings` can be modified as follows:

```
public sealed class Settings
{
    private Settings() { }

    public static Settings GetSettings() { return instance.Value; }

    private static Lazy<Settings> instance = 
        new Lazy<Settings>(() =>
                            {
                                var settings = new Settings();
                                using (var textReader = new StreamReader(SettingsPath.Instance.FullName, Encoding.UTF8 ))
                                {
                                    JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Populate(textReader, settings);
                                }
                                
                                return settings;
                            });

    // Remainder of Settings unchanged
    
    [JsonProperty]
    public Guid ApplicationId { get; private set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string AccessToken { get; private set; }
}

internal sealed class SettingsPath
{
    // Nested global singleton, used for lazy thread-safe initialization of settings directory.  
    private SettingsPath(string fullName) { this.FullName = fullName; }
    
    public static SettingsPath Instance { get { return instance.Value; } }

    static Lazy<SettingsPath> instance = 
        new Lazy<SettingsPath>(() =>
                               {
                                   var folder = Path.Combine( Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData ), "Company Name", "Program Name" );
                                   try
                                   {
                                       var directory = Directory.CreateDirectory( folder );
                                   }
                                   catch ( Exception x )
                                   {
                                       Debug.WriteLine( string.Format("Unable to create settings folder: {0}", folder ));
                                       throw;
                                   }
                                   var fileName = Path.Combine( folder, "settings.json" );
                                   return new SettingsPath(fileName);
                               });
    
    public string FullName { get; private set; } // You could save the directory and file name as well, if necessary
}
```

Notes:

- Using `Populate()` looks cleaner in my opinion.  `Settings` is supposed to be a singleton, and in this version of the code the `Settings` object is shown to be constructed only once, from within the class itself.
- When deserializing from a file, Newtonsoft recommends deserializing directly from a stream for performance reasons. See [Performance Tips: Optimize Memory Usage](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#MemoryUsage) for details.
- I extracted the settings directory into its own lazily initialized `SettingsPath` singleton because it looked cleaner, and in case you need access to the settings directory elsewhere in your code.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ocAtyv).

Comment: I applied all the suggestions and the problem is fixed. Thanks.